# Reference counting on PyErr_Fetch/PyErr_NormalizeException results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

`PyErr_Fetch` doesn't always return a triplet where the second argument is a `PyException` so, to ease the parsing, you *might want* to use `PyErr_NormalizeException` to sort that part out (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_NormalizeException))

What the documentation doesn't say, however, is how normalize exception treats the original results of `PyErr_Fetch` in terms of memory retention when it creates the new exception instance.

Can I assume that *whatever `PyErr_NormalizeException` does* to the pointers of `PyErr_Fetch` I can `PyErr_Restore` them and be "ok" as far as memory is concerned?

I would say that this is the case, but maybe I'm missing a detail and I need to "do something" to the original fetch results instead.

Thank you!

Comment: If you search https://github.com/python/cpython for `PyErr_NormalizeException` then it looks like your assumption matches how it's used internally. Definitely doesn't mean I'm confident of that answer though

Comment: Thank you for your remark, @DavidW (I admit I should have looked at the sources myself: shame on me): it also checks out with the projected use of the object (normalize will _most likely_ give the ownership of the ``pvalue`` to the newly created exception, so everything will balance out :) ). Cheers!